# I set Windows C: drive as active and now my Ubuntu partition has become free space (unallocated)

Tags: dual-boot, windows, grubrescue, unallocated

I was running Windows under dual-boot with Ubuntu 14.04.

I accidentally opened Windows native disk manager and set the `C:` drive as active.
It turned my Ubuntu extended partition into free space (unallocated space).
Now my computer does not boot, showing grub rescue prompt.

I booted using an Ubuntu live CD, and ran Gparted. Gparted also shows the space unallocated.

So, have I completely lost my Ubuntu installation and files? Is there a way to recover my Ubuntu installation and files?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using GNU Parted.
Other methods of recovering are mentioned in the [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery).
Advantage of choosing GNU Parted:
No need to download it, it is included in Ubuntu base.

> **How to use GNU Parted**
>
> Run Parted from the command line to recover your partition.
>
> When changing the partition table on your hard drive, you must ensure
>   that no partition on the disk is mounted. This includes swap space.
>   The easiest way to accomplish this is to run the live cd. Parted is
>   installed on the base Ubuntu system. Once at the desktop, open a
>   terminal and run_:
>
> ```
> sudo swapoff -a or you can use Gparted partition editor to achieve the same. Next run parted and tell it to use the device in question.
> ```
>
> For example, if your /dev/sda drive is the drive from which you want
>   to recover, run:
>
> ```
> sudo parted /dev/sda
> ```

Enter the following command to ensure the unit used is 's':

```
unit s
```

Now you can use the print and rescue command to recover your partition as explained in [the user manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/rescue.html) as follows:

Enter the following command to get details of all partitions and their start and end locations:

```
print
```

Now we can enter the final rescue command:

```
rescue START END
```

Use the values for start and end from the output of the `print` command.

If you have more than one partition to recover, repeat you rescue command.

You won't need to restore GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

I would go about it in these steps:

- Boot the Ubuntu Live CD
- `sudo apt-get install testdisk`
- Run `testdisk`, and try to recover the partition from there.

Probably Windows just removed the partition definition from the partition table, which will take just a few seconds for `testdisk` to fix. Then `grub` should also work automagically. If the problem's worse, `testdisk` may only be able to recover some of your files; in that case I'd deem it unfeasible to fix the installation itself; I'd just back up the files worth backing up and reinstall Ubuntu.